# Remove line in host's known_host file through Vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I've narrowed down [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141948/mysql-ssh-vagrant-connection-only-works-once) question - regarding a MySQL over SSH connection only working once - to a conflicting line in my host computer's `known_hosts` file.

Essentially, I can not get into my Database GUI of choice because the key is different for the same IP address (after re-provisioning, reloading, etc.).

Once I delete any offending lines, I can get in just fine.

So, through Vagrant's shell command (that I'm provisioning with) how can I modify the **host machine's** `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file?

**EDIT:**
I found a temp fix that involves adding/creating a `~/.ssh/config` file (this involves using a private IP address):

```
Host 192.168.*.*
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Should let you in.  Not a real fix, as this kind of fix can be a security concern.  Look below for much better answer.

Comment: Oh, my freaking God! I completely missed "host" word! D: My answer is all about guest OS! (facepalm) I led you to totaly wrong direction. Sorry

Comment: Edited my answer. Now it's actually an answer to your question. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for taking you away from what you need!

**Changing HOST files from Vagrantfile:**

What you actually want is very simple. Vagrantfile is interpreted by Vagrant each time you run vagrant command. It is regular ruby code, so if you want to change HOST file, all you need to do is to put in the Vagrantfile Ruby code that performs this change. Here's the example code I've put at the end of my Vagrantfile:

```
require 'tempfile' 
require 'fileutils'  

path = '~/.ssh/known_hosts' 
temp_file = Tempfile.new('foo') 
begin   
  File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      if line !~ /REGEX_OF_LINE_YOU_WANT_TO_EXCLUDE/ then
        temp_file.puts line
      end
    end
  end   
  temp_file.rewind   
  FileUtils.mv(temp_file.path, path) 
  ensure   
    temp_file.close
    temp_file.unlink
  end
```

Note to edit the code above by putting your own value for `REGEX_OF_LINE_YOU_WANT_TO_EXCLUDE`.

Hope I at least partially fixed my mistake by providing this answer :)

---

#### Original Answer

*For anyone's (mine as well) future reference, I'm leaving part of the answer that refers to changing GUEST OS files or copying files to GUEST OS:*

Vagrant provides couple of [provisioners](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html).

**Solution number 1:** For simple file copy you may use Vagrant **file provisioner**. Following code in your Vagrantfile would copy the file `~/known_hosts.template` from your host system to VM's file `/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts`

> ```
> # Context -------------------------------------------------------
> Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
>   # ...
>
>   # This is the section to add ----------------------------------
>   config.vm.provision :file do |file|
>     file.source      = '~/known_hosts.template'
>     file.destination = '/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts'
>   end
>   #--------------------------------------------------------------
> end
> ```

File provisioner is poorly documented on Vagrant site, and we've got to thank @tmatilai who had answered [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/565281/how-to-upload-configuration-files-using-the-shell-provider) on serverfault.

Keep in mind that you should use **absolute** paths in **destination** field, and that copying is being performed by vagrant user, so file will have vagrant's owner:group.

**Solution number 2:** If you need to copy file with a root privileges, or really have to change the file without using templates, consider using well documented [**shell provisioner**](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html). File copying in this case would work only if you have the file placed in the folder visible from within the VM(guestOS), but you have all the power of shell.

**Solution number 3:** Though it would be overkill in this case, you might use very powerful **Chef** or **Puppet** as provisioners, and perform action via one of those frameworks. I know nothing about Puppet, and may talk only about Chef. Cookbook would be very simple. Create template file (.erb) with desired content, and then your recipe will just place the file where necessary. Of course you'll need a box with Chef packeges in it.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  Will definitely look into it.  Mitchell has replied on Github as I also filed a bug for this with some good information, basically explaining this is a bug that has been fixed in the git version of Vagrant, but no in the installer yet.  https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3515

Comment: There also was a suggestion to use a ~/.ssh/config file with the selected IP (I was using a private IP, so that seems like it could work well too) to disable checking and storing in the known_hosts file for that given request.  I appreciate the Hammer solution, and I'm currently strengthening my skills with Puppet and Chef as I go to understand your solution too. However, I'm having a lot of problems with Puppet right now even configuring a base webserver, so it may be some time before I can implement anything.

Answer (score 1):

I use plain ssh to enter my machines in order to do provisioning:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

With this setup the known hosts is bound to give problems, but I do not want to turn off the host key checking as I use that also for external hosts. Given my hosts include pattern foo, I did this on the shell:

```
$ ssh -i '' '/foo/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Remove the empty '' argument after -i if you have GNU/linux host in stead of BSD/MacOSX.

You can then install the vagrant trigger plugin:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

And add the above snippet to the Vagrantfile (mind the backticks):

```
config.trigger.after :destroy do
   puts "Removing known host entries"
   `sed -i '' '/foo/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
end
```

Comment: But if I disable host key checking only for local IPs (or that private IP I use over and over for all Vagrant) am I not still checking it on every other outbound request that setting isn't limited to?

Comment: do you mean `$ sed -i '' '/foo/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts` instead of `$ ssh -i '' '/foo/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

I define the `IP_ADDRESS` and `DOMAIN_NAME` variables at the top of the Vagrantfile.

Then inside `Vagrant.configure` I add:

```
config.trigger.after :destroy do |trigger|
  trigger.info = "Removing known_hosts entries"
  trigger.run = {inline: "ssh-keygen -R #{IP_ADDRESS}"}
  trigger.run = {inline: "ssh-keygen -R #{DOMAIN_NAME}"}
end
```